# Enable sliding expiration for any cookie with asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

Identity cookies have an option to set Sliding expiration. However if we create a normal cookie, it doesn't have a sliding option but an absolute value. If I want to have a custom cookie(s) to support sliding expiration;

1. I will have to store the time created in the cookie with the expiration.
2. When the server receives the cookie, compare the created time with expiration time and then update the cookie if required with new expiration time.

Am I right that this feature is not provided by the framework? May be I didn't look enough?

If I have to do a custom implementation for sliding expiration, what's the best place to do that? Should I write a middleware?

As I feel, the updating of the cookie should happen in the pipeline where the data is going out because updating the cookie for incoming requests won't make sense.

Can someone shed some light around this? I am using asp.net core on .Net 5.

Comment: Hi, you can use [CookieAuthenticationOptions.SlidingExpiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.slidingexpiration?view=aspnetcore-6.0) property to achieve your requirement.

Comment: @Rena This option is only available for AuthenticationCookies. In my case it's just a normal cookie which I store some random data; but I want that cookie to support sliding expiration. For that this property won't work.